# Calculatin yearly accumulative growth rate by months in ts object in R?

Tags: r, package, time-series

I have been trying to create a yearly acumulative growth rate by months with the growth.rate function from the "tis" package. I have done some modifications in my case.

For example, in the next time serie in March 2017 (obs=38). I want to estimate the accumulative growth rate between the months January to March in 2017, divided by January to March in 2016 and minus 1 and multiplied by 100 (as the function shows).

How can I do the this yearly accumulative growth rate? Any idea would be very apreciated.

```
library(tis)

x<-38:76
xts<-ts(x,start=c(2014,1),frequency = 12)
growth.rate_mod<-
function (x, lag = 1) 
{
  xts <- as.tis(xts)
  lx <- lag(xts, -lag)
  dx <- diff(xts, lag = lag)
  f.over.l <- as.vector(frequency(xts)/lag)
      100 * (xts/lx -1)
  }

growth.rate_mod(xts, lag = 1)
growth.rate_mod(xts, lag = 12)
```

If these are the growth rate for lag 1  and lag 12

100 * ((x[t]/x[t-1]) - 1) this is lag =1 
100 * ((x[t]/x[t-12]) - 1) this is lag =12

So, the *yearly accumulative growth rate* I want to do is:

100 * ( sum(x[t-i] to x[t] /sum(x[t-[i-12] to x[t-12]) ) - 1)

Where, 
i = it would be the time distance between Jan to Mar if t =3. It could be change between 1 to 12 (Jan to Dic)

Thanks in advance!